# JGraphX: Reposition edge terminal on vertices

Tags: java, jgraphx

I've a graph with 18 vertices and lots of edges. Due to the number of elements involved and their structure the built-in algorithms available (i.e. mxHierarchicalLayout used for the shown image ) are not working as expected, causing the majority of edges with description to overlap, as shown in the picture 
[Current status sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixTAc.png).

Doing some tests and checks in the source code I managed to change only few things on the edges trough the geometry of the mxCell:

- Edge lable
- Control points

However I'm not finding any way to manipulate the point of the source and target terminals. Can anyone suggest me the proper classes/methods to be used to control where the terminal should be connected.

Any help/info would be appreciated.

The code I managed to test to manipulate the edges is the following:

```
..
    Arrays.asList(edges).stream().map(edge -> (mxCell) edge).forEach(edge -> {
            mxGeometry newGeo = (mxGeometry) edge.getGeometry().clone();
            // TODO calculate condition
            // This code actually move the label from the default
            // position
            mxPoint offset = new mxPoint(edge.getGeometry().getPoint().getX() + EDGE_OFFSET,
                    edge.getGeometry().getPoint().getY() + EDGE_OFFSET);
            newGeo.setOffset(offset);
            newGeo.setX(newGeo.getX() + 1);
            if (newGeo.getPoints() != null) {
                newGeo.getPoints().forEach(point -> {
                    point.setX(point.getX() + 200);
                    point.setY(point.getY() + 200);
                });
            }
            model.setGeometry(edge,newGeo);
    });
```

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

The position of source and target terminals are determined according to the shape of the cell and its border. This can be obtained by using `mxGraphView.getPerimeterPoint(cellState, point...)`, and which uses `mxGraphView.getPerimeterFunction` and `mxGraphView.getPerimeterBounds`.

This works well for an initial placement of edge labels (I use this to place multiple edge labels--such as cardinalities in UML class diagrams).

However, this method uses an `mxCellState` and for some reason I do not yet know it cannot be used when repositioning using an `mxEventListener` on move events. cell states are still set on the previous position of the cell when events are fired.